# How to write tests in Python using unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I want to write my library in TDD methodology, but I have no idea how to design directory structure (or how to use `unittest`). Now I create a directory tree such as:

```
myproject (directory)
    - tests (directory)
    - src (directory)
    - test.py (file running tests)
```

Each class from `src` has its own `unittest` class. Each directory has its own `__init__.py` file. I want to run tests only from `test.py` file and thanks to this each test can `from src.modulename import classname` and than runs test `unittest.main()` function. Unfortunately it doesn't work (runs zero tests).

Is this good approach? What are my mistakes?

Comment: Have you looked at doc testing? http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html I always liked its simplicity

Comment: Yes I have. I have plenty of tests written in `unittest` and if it is possible I would rather use them instead of rewrite on another framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in file `test.py` should look like:

```
from tests import *
import unittest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testsuite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('.')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(testsuite)
```

This code copies all tests from `tests` directory, because it copies entire package. The main method runs all test methods included in `tests` package's classes. **Each test file name must start with `test`.**